# do I need to apply for esta if I have a b2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, esta, applications

hi there I have a visa b2 do I need to apply for esta on line?

thanks

Comment: You do not need ESTA and you should not apply for it.  ESTA is for people who want to use the visa waiver program.  People who travel to the US with a visa are not using the visa waiver program.  When you enter the US, present your passport open to the visa page, so the officer does not mistakenly admit you under the visa waiver program.